# Search a complex data structure in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm relatively new to Python, so I'm teaching myself as I go along.
I need to write a script that parses a JSON output, which looks something like that:

```
[{u'serverId': 117, u'hostName': u'bla', u'ipAddress': u'10.0.0.1', u'id': 163},
{u'serverId': 221, u'hostName': u'bla2', u'ipAddress': u'10.0.0.1', u'id': 380},
{u'serverId': 213, u'hostName': u'bla2', u'ipAddress': u'10.0.0.3', u'id': 658}]
```

and so on, and so on...

I have a primary data source, that i iterate through to get the host names.
The secondary source (above) is needed for the server id.

How can i use the hostname from the 1st data source to get the corresponding id?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks like Python, not JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as a one-liner using `filter()`:

```
filter(lambda d: d['hostName'] == hostName, json.loads(data))
```

This will return either an empty list or a list of elements of your data (in dictionary form) for which the hostName key is equal to `hostName`. You can then use that as follows:

```
entries = filter(
    lambda d: d['hostName'] == hostName,
    json.loads(data)
)

if not entries:
    raise KeyError('There is no entry with that host name.')

id = entries[0]['id']
```

Comment: Thanks! that seemed to work. I liked the elegance of this one liner :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
my_list = []

# Read in json file
with open('file.json') as in_file:
    my_list = json.load(in_file) 

for row in my_list:  # Loop through the array
    if isinstance(row, dict):  # Check we are dealing with a dictionary
        if row.get('hostName', '') == 'bla':  # compare values
            print(row.get('id', None))  # Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to use a key (in your case, the hostname) to look up another piece of data (in your case, the server ID), generally the most appropriate data structure in Python is a dictionary.  In this case, you would want to build a dictionary from your JSON data, something like this:

```
server_id_mapping = {}
for server_info in json.loads(data_source_2):
    server_id_mapping[server_info['hostName']] = server_info['serverId']
```

Then, to get the server ID from a hostname, just use:

```
server_id = server_id_mapping[hostname]
```